# JAR manifest application-library-allowable-codebase mismatch

Tags: java, applet

I have added application-library-allowable-codebase: http://my.host.name/myapp/* to my applet jar manifest file. I could run/launch the applet from my JSP but when I run/call it from asp.net application I get below error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: JAR manifest application-library-allowable-codebase  mismatch for http://my.host.name/myapp/lib/applet.jar
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployManifestChecker.verify(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployManifestChecker.verify(Unknown Source)
... 30 more
```

Can someone say what I have to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding my applet running domain name and dot net application domain fixed the issue.

```
application-library-allowable-codebase: http://my.host.name/ http://my.donetapp.host.name/
```

Comment: You should mark this as the correct answer if it solved your problem

Answer (score 1):

From documentation [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/security/manifest.html#codebase):

> An asterisk (*) can be used as a wildcard only at the beginning of the domain name, and cannot be used with only a top-level domain, such as *.com.

So you cannot use `http://your.host/app/*` because wildcard (*) is at the end. You can write just `http://my.host.name`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have changed but still I am getting the same error.

Comment: How did you use asterisk? Could you post example please or your manifest file.

Comment: <jar destfile="${jarFile}" update="true">
 <manifest>
  <attribute name="Permissions" value="all-permissions" />
  <attribute name="Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase" value="http://my.host.name:8081" />
  <attribute name="Caller-Allowable-Codebase" value="http://my.host.name:8081" />
 </manifest>
</jar>

Comment: After reading whole error message I think, you should skip port number - error message: `mismatch for http://my.host.name/myapp/lib/applet.jar`, but in manifest you have `my.host.name:8081`. Tell me later, if this is helpful.